# Setting bounds to combination of two GeoJSON layers in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, extents, geodjango

I am creating an app with django, geodjango and Leaflet, I am also using django-geojson and django-leaflet.

I manage to insert on a map two features that contain points. But I am getting problems setting the bounds for that map. Since I am adding two sets of points to the map I would like to set the bounds to the combination of both sets. But when I try to use

```
   var features = L.control.layers(basemaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
   map.fitBounds(features.getBounds());
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: features.getBounds is not a function

The idea is that I want to set the bound to the combination of feature_incidence and feature_warnings.

This is my code:

```
var geom_incidence = {{ incidences|geojsonfeature|safe }};
  var feature_incidence = L.geoJson(geom_incidence , { pointToLayer:redIcon});
  var geom_warnings = {{ mobile_warnings|geojsonfeature|safe }};
  var feature_warnings = L.geoJson(geom_warnings, { pointToLayer:blueIcon});

  var basemaps = {

    "osmHOT" : L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors, Tiles style by Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team hosted by OpenStreetMap France'
    }),
    "Calles": L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    })
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Incidencias": feature_incidence,
    "Avisos":feature_warnings
};
var features = L.control.layers(basemaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(features.getBounds());

feature_incidence.addTo(map);
feature_warnings.addTo(map);
basemaps["Calles"].addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.control.layers` is Leaflet control and as such does not return layers features, but Leaflet control object, which has no `.getBounds` method.

If you want to get bounds of combined `feature_incidence` and `feature_warnings` layers, you can first get bounds of one layer with the `.getBounds` method and then extend it with the bounds of the other layer using bounds `.extend` method (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds).

Code could then look something like this:

```
var bounds1 = feature_incidence.getBounds();
var bounds2 = feature_warnings.getBounds();

map.fitBounds(bounds1.extend(bound2));
```